# Python Recursive Example Explanation

Tags: python, function, recursion

So currently working through MIT's OpenCourseWare computer science course online and I am having trouble trying to understand one of the recursive examples.

```
def f(L):
    result = []
    for e in L:
        if type(e) != list:
            result.append(e)
        else:
            return f(e)
return result
```

When the following input is given:

```
print f([1, [[2, 'a'], ['a','b']], (3, 4)])
```

The output is:

```
[2, 'a']
```

I am having trouble trying to understand how this function actually works or what it is doing. Shouldn't the function eventually be adding every string or int into the result list? I just need help with trying to understand how this function "winds up" and "unwinds"

I feel like the output should be:

```
[1,2,'a','a','b',3,4]
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: The code returns a copy of the first flat list it encounters (in depth first search).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `f` returns a (shallow) **copy of the first flat list it encounters with depth first search**.

Why? Well first let us take a look at the *base case*: a list that contains **no** lists. Like `[1,'a',2,5]`. In that case the the `if` statement will **always** succeed, and therefore all elements of `e` will be added to the `result` and the `result` is returned.

Now what about the recursive case. This means there **is** an element that is a list. Like for instance `[1,['a',2],5]`. Now for the first element, the `if` succeeds, so `1` is added to the `result` list. But for the second element `['a',2]` the `if` **fails**. This means we perform a recursive call on `f` with `['a',2]`. Now since that list does not contain any sublists, we know it will return a copy of that list.

Note however that we **immediately `return`** the result of that recursive call. So from the moment we take the `else` branch, the `result` is of **no importance** anymore: we will return what that `f(e)` returns.

If we make the assumption we cannot construct a loop of infinite deep sublists (actually we can, but in that case we will get a stack overflow exception), we will eventually obtain a flat list and obtain that copy.

**Example**: If we take your sample input `[1, [[2, 'a'], ['a','b']], (3, 4)]`. We can *trace* the calls. So we first call `f` on that list, it will generate the following "trace":

```
# **trace** of an example function call
f([1, [[2, 'a'], ['a','b']], (3, 4)]):
    result = []
    # for 1 in L:
    # if type(1) == list: # fails
    # else
    result.append(1) # result is now [1]
    # for [[2,'a'],['a','b']] in L:
    # if type([[2,'a'],['a','b']]) == list: succeeds
    return f([[2,'a'],['a','b']])
                      result = []
                      # for [2,'a'] in L:
                      # if type([2,'a']) == list: succeeds
                      return f([2,'a'])
                                        result = []
                                        # for 2 in L:
                                        # if type(2) == list: fails
                                        # else:
                                        result.append(2) # result is now [2]
                                        # for 'a' in [2,'a']:
                                        # if type('a') == list: fails
                                        # else:
                                        result.append('a') # result is now [2,'a']
                                        return [2,'a']
                      return [2,'a']
    return [2,'a']
```

**Flattening**:

Given you wanted to *flatten* the list instead of returning the first flat list, you can rewrite the code to:

```
def f(L):
    result = []
    for e in L:
        if type(e) != list:
            result.append(e)
        else:
            result += f(e)
    return result
```

Note that this will **only flatten `list`s** (and not even subclasses of `list`s).

Answer (score 1):

so by your suggested answer I see that you understand about the idea of the code. It digs deeper and deeper until it finds an element. But look about the back-step to the upper levels:

When it reaches the deepest point for the first time (the elements of the [2,'a'] list) it finish the loop on this level and returns the results 2 and a. And here is a RETURN statement ... that means the loop is stoped and thus no other elements are found.

The open question is now, why it is not showing 1 as part of result ? For the same reason, the RETURN is the result of the lower levels (2,a) and the result of the upper level. If you change "result" to a global variable, the outcome will be [1, 2, 'a']

best regards

Answer (score 0):

The function as posted returns/exits when running into a first bottom-down list-element which doesn't contain a list - this prevents walking all the further branches of the recursion. For example:

```
print( f([1, [[2, 'a', [3, 'b', [4, 'c']]], ['a','b']], (3, 4)]) )
# gives: [4, 'c']
print( f([1, ['X','Y'], [[2, 'a', [3, 'b', [4, 'c']]], ['a','b']], (3, 4)]) )
# gives: ['X','Y']
```

The key point causing this behaviour is the line

```
result = []
```

This resets the list with results on each call of the function to an empty list. This way only one item is returned up from the chain of the recursion calls.

By the way the function f below does what you have expected, doesn't it?

```
def f(L, result):
    for e in L:
        if type(e) != list:
            result.append(e)
        else:
            f(e, result)

result=[]; f([1, [[2, 'a', [3, 'b', [4, 'c']]], ['a','b']], (3, 4)], result) print( result )
# gives: [1, 2, 'a', 3, 'b', 4, 'c', 'a', 'b', (3, 4)]
result=[]; f( [1, ['X','Y'], [[2, 'a', [3, 'b', [4, 'c']]], ['a','b']], (3, 4)], result); print( result )
# gives: [1, 'X', 'Y', 2, 'a', 3, 'b', 4, 'c', 'a', 'b', (3, 4)]
```

NOTICE: (3,4) is a TUPLE not a list ...

The function f as above collects items from a list if these items are not a list themselves. In the special case, when the item in the list is a list, the function calls itself to collect the items from this list. This way all they way down of the hierarchy every element is collected, no matter how deep one needs to dig down. This is the beauty of recursion - a function calling itself does the 'magic' of visiting all of the branches and their leaves down a tree :)

Comment: How is this the answer. The question is not "*What is wrong with this function?*". The question is "*Why does this function gives another output than what I expected it to be?*".

Comment: Furthermore your code **does not produce** the correct result: you do not `+=` the output of `f(e)`...

Comment: reread the question and show me where it is stated that there is **anything** wrong with the posted code? The OP simply found the code fragment and found out it does not do what they expected... Not because it is wrong, but because the purpose is different...

Comment: My function produces here: 
`[1, 2, 'a', 'a', 'b', (3, 4)]`